# Different orientations between smartphones and tablets

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app and I need that the screen is in portrait for smartphones and portrait / landscape for tablets. The client does not want to accept different applications and wishes the orientation locked on smartphone. My solution was to create a bool value as amending the screen size, but the application closes the smartphone to start it when the device is in landscape. The main class extends the NoRotateScreen class, the code inside it:

```
   boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
   if (!tabletSize) {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   }
```

The file sets the boolean file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

What I can do?

Comment: The client said they want the orientation to be *unlocked*, but you are asking StackOverflow how to *lock* it to portrait? I am confused.

Comment: Where is your boolean file located? Place one in `res/values` and set isTablet to false. Then, place one in `res/values-sw600dp` and set isTablet to true.

Comment: # John - I fixed the text.
# BVB - The file is located inside values-SW600dp(true) and values-SW350dp(false).

Comment: just place another false inside `values`. this `false` will be your default value

Comment: Yes, it works but crash on startscreen

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim what is logcat output on the crash?